# error while running code in angular project

Tags: angular

ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | 
>       | ^
>     2 |     Angular Tutorial
>     3 |       Go to list

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share?

Comment: You have this error because